# Customise order file

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In this code, i would like to have the **stars** before the **product name**. Also how to add line breaks `\n` How to do this ?

```
<?php 
    $Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection() 
        // ->setPageSize(5) 
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
        ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) 
        ->addRateVotes() 
        ->setDateOrder('created_at', 'asc'); 
    $_items = array_reverse( $Collection->getItems());
?>

<?php foreach ($_items as $_review): ?>
    <?php
        $productId = $_review->getentity_pk_value(); 
        $current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        echo '<a href="' . $current_product->getProductUrl() . '"><h3>' . $current_product->getName() . '</h3></a>';
        echo $_review->getTitle(); 
        echo $_review->getDetail();
        echo $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt());
        $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
    ?>

    <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
        <table class="ratings-table">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="review-label" />
                <col class="review-value" />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                <tr>
               <!-- <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th> -->
                    <td>
                        <div class="rating-box">
                            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
echo '<a href="' . $current_product->getProductUrl() . '"><h3>' . $current_product->getName() . '</h3></a>';
```

after `<?php endif; ?>` and you will get the stars above the name.
but put `<?php`before the `echo` and `?>` after the semicolon.

Also you can use `<br />` for line breaks. It HTML.

Note: this code hurts my eyes.

Comment: thanks, but i ment before instead of above. Actually i would like it to look exaclty like this:

stars - product name <br/>
review title - review <br/>

Does it really hurt the eyes that bad? i am a complete noob in coding. can you explain what hurts or even better make the code look like how you think it should look. Always looking for improvement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br />` already suggested or use `<p>` and  `<h1> , <h2>, <h3> ect` to split sections into headings and paragraphs which will usually line break upon the closing tag (depending on CSS). I have updated code with example of what you want it like below:

```
<?php 
$Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection() 
//->setPageSize(5) 
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) 
->addRateVotes() 
->setDateOrder('created_at', 'asc'); 
$_items = array_reverse( $Collection->getItems());

foreach ($_items as $_review): 
  $productId = $_review->getentity_pk_value(); 
  $current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

  $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
  if (count($_votes)): ?>
    <table class="ratings-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="review-label" />
        <col class="review-value" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="rating-box">
                    <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $current_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
  <h3><?php echo $current_product->getName(); ?></h3></a>    
  <h2><?php echo $_review->getTitle(); ?></h2>
  <p><?php echo $_review->getDetail(); ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()); ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The code is a little ugly however it will do the trick. It's normally frowned upon to use collections within template files and is best practice to create a module with a block that handles that side of things. So your module will do all the data collection, get the name and url etc. and this template file will just be used for displaying the data collected within the block.